# Generate objects to fill datetime space

Tags: c#, algorithm

i have a list, which Time class is:

```
public class Time
{
   public DateTime From { get; set; }
   public DateTime To { get; set; }
}
```

That list is filled with objects Time coming from DB. So, at the end of the process, I have the list with objects that can have time gaps between them, for example:

```
Time1: 
  From: 1/1/2017 12:00
  To: 1/1/2017 13:00
Time2: 
  From: 1/1/2017 13:00
  To: 1/1/2017 16:00
Time3: 
  From: 1/1/2017 20:00
  To: 1/1/2017 22:00
```

So, I should create three objects Time like this:

```
Time4: 
  From: 1/1/2017 00:00
  To: 1/1/2017 11:00
Time5: 
  From: 1/1/2017 16:00
  To: 1/1/2017 20:00
Time6: 
  From: 1/1/2017 22:00
  To: 1/1/2017 23:59
```

The idea is to have the list with all datetime complete, leaving no time slots in the middle.

So, as I said, the objects Time 1, 2, 3 I already have it, because they are generated from DB, but I need to make an algorithm to generate the objects Time 4, 5, 6.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a custom logic to fill in the missing time slots based on the list which is auto populated from the DB. You need to run (iterate) the loop and compare the time `From` value and create a new object of `Time` class at run time with dynamic values and insert it into the list.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the dates. Create a begin date. Iterate.

**DEMO**: https://repl.it/Eqbd/0

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class MainClass {

  public class Time
  {
     public DateTime From { get; set; }
     public DateTime To { get; set; }
     public string Src { get; private set; }

     public Time(){
       Src = "DB";
     }

     public Time Gap(DateTime prev) {
       if(prev >= this.From) return null;
       return new Time {From = prev, To = this.From, Src="GAP"};
     }

     public static Time Gap(DateTime from, DateTime to){
       if(from >= to) return null;
       return new Time {From = from, To = to, Src="GAP"};
     }

     override public string ToString(){
       return $"Time: {Src}\n\t{From}\n\t{To}";
     }
  }



  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    var times = new List<Time>();
    times.Add(new Time {From = DateTime.Parse("1/1/2017 12:00 PM"), To=DateTime.Parse("1/1/2017 13:00 PM")});
    times.Add(new Time {From = DateTime.Parse("1/1/2017 13:00 PM"), To=DateTime.Parse("1/1/2017 16:00 PM")});
    times.Add(new Time {From = DateTime.Parse("1/1/2017 20:00 PM"), To=DateTime.Parse("1/1/2017 22:00 PM")});

    // Begin

    times.Sort((a, b) => a.From.CompareTo(b.From));

    var prev = DateTime.Parse("1/1/2017 00:00 AM");
    var last = prev.AddDays(1).AddMilliseconds(-1);
    Time gap;

    foreach(var time in times.ToArray()) {
      gap = time.Gap(prev);
      if(gap != null) {
        times.Add(gap);
      }
      prev = time.To;
    }

    gap = Time.Gap(prev, last);
    if(gap != null) {
      times.Add(gap);
    }

    foreach(var time in times){
      Console.WriteLine (time);
    }

  }
}
```